# ngModel on number input

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I'd like to bind the input of a number input to a variable in my typescript file. I thought ngModel would be appropriate and made an input: `<input [{ngModel}]="tRating" type="number" min="1" max="10">` tRating being of type number in the .ts file. Unfortunately I'm getting an error :

```
Can't bind to '{ngModel}' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("   
        <input [ERROR ->][{ngModel}]="pRating" type="number" min="1" max="10">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to import **`FormsModule`** into your app.module.ts

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
         FormsModule      
    ],
```

and syntax should be **`[(ngModel)]`** not **`[{ngModel}]`**

```
<input [(ngModel)]="tRating" type="number" min="1" max="10">
```

Answer (score -1):

if you use ngForm ,

```html
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" novalidate>
  <input name="tRating" ngModel required #tRating="ngModel">
....
```